# Very weird issue with elasticsearch, confusing data in fieldata_fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index `http://127.0.0.1:9200/7fba4764eba5e00e4afcaa46b52690f2/`

Now if I open this url,

`http://127.0.0.1:9200/7fba4764eba5e00e4afcaa46b52690f2/_search?q=source_id:1832`

I will not get any data

If I add type in that search, I will get desired data

`http://127.0.0.1:9200/7fba4764eba5e00e4afcaa46b52690f2/trash/_search?q=source_id:1832`

I don't know how to debug this issue, so I tried to dump the data stored in memory with this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "*"
        }
    },
    "fielddata_fields": [ "source_id" ]
}
```

And the `source_id` part was totally a mess, any ideas?

```
"fields" : {
        "source_id" : [
                      " \u0001\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000e(",
                      "0 \u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
                      "@\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
                      "P\u0002\u0000\u0000"
                   ]
                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is similar to, if not the same as the problem posted here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30269676/382774. From my answer on that topic:

> https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8614 - identical field
>   names in different mappings need to share the same type.

It's a bug they're working on.